# How can I get a list of already define contextIds for the extension point org.eclipse.ui.bindings?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, key-bindings

I'd like to bind a new keyboard shortcut to an existing context in my `plugin.xml`. How can I get a list of all known `contextId`s?

Specifically, I'm looking for a context ID that will bind the shortcut to the Project Explorer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you create a `key` binding in the plugin.xml editor there is a `Browse` button on the `contextId` line that will show you a list of know context ids.